# Xamarin.Forms trying to communicate between JavaScript and C#

Tags: javascript, c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

OK... so I have a Custom HTMLWebview which I want to add Javascript to. A lot of examples I find online have the HTML on Android (and iOS) level but I would prefer keeping the HTML in the Custom Renderer (that way I can fill it with custom content on seperate pages).

Right now I have a button which should fire an event but it is not happening and I'm not sure why.

This is my Custom Renderer:

```
    public class HybridWebView : WebView
    {
        public HybridWebView()
        {
            const string html = @"
        <html>
          <body>
            <h3>Test page</h3>
            <button type=""button"" onClick=""CSharp.ShowToast('Hello from JS')"">Native Interaction</button>
          </body>
        </html>";

            var htmlSource = new HtmlWebViewSource();
           htmlSource.BaseUrl = DependencyService.Get<IBaseUrl>().Get();

            htmlSource.Html = html;
            Source = htmlSource;
        }
    }
```

This is my Android Renderer:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(HybridWebView), typeof(HybridWebViewRenderer))]
namespace Test.Droid.Renderers
{
    public class HybridWebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer
    {

        Context _context;
        public HybridWebViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
                Control.AddJavascriptInterface(new HybridJSBridge(Android.App.Application.Context), "CSharp");

            }

            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
        }

    }
}
```

This is my bridge:

```
    public class HybridJSBridge : Java.Lang.Object
    {
        Context context;

        public HybridJSBridge(Context context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }

        [JavascriptInterface]
        [Export]
        public void ShowToast(string msg)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(context, msg, ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }

    }
```

Right now nothing happens when the button is pressed. I hope someone can point me in the right direction? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Never worked with this, but are you sure it should be `CSharp.ShowToast` and not `HybridJSBridge.ShowToast`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to achieve the result like following GIF?

[image]

I do not know what value of `BaseUrl` 
 in `htmlSource.BaseUrl = DependencyService.Get<IBaseUrl>().Get();` , If I set the value of `return "file:///android_asset";`

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(BaseUrl_Android))]
namespace WebviewInvokeJS.Droid
{
    class BaseUrl_Android : IBaseUrl
    {
        public string Get()
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();

            return "file:///android_asset";
        }
    }
}
```

and add `Control.SetWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());` in `HybridWebViewRenderer` it worked.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(HybridWebView), typeof(HybridWebViewRenderer))]
namespace WebviewInvokeJS.Droid
{

    public class HybridWebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer
    {
        Context _context;
        public HybridWebViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
                Control.AddJavascriptInterface(new HybridJSBridge(Android.App.Application.Context), "CSharp");
               Control.SetWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
            }

            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
        }
    }


}
```

You also could download my demo to make a test.

https://github.com/851265601/XFormsWebviewInvokeJS

Comment: If the answer is helpful, please mark it (click the "✔" at the top right corner of this answer ), it will help others who have similar issues.